# Excel - VBA - Function detecting image in cell

Tags: excel, vba, function

I wanted to write a function that detects if there is an Image in the cell. When not, it goes to the next row. The column stays the same.

My Function doesnt work.

```
Public Function HasImage(ByVal Target As Range) As Boolean
Dim bResult As Boolean
Dim shp As Shape
     bResult = False
         For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
             If shp.TopLeftCell.Address = Target.Address _
                     And shp.BottomRightCell.Address = Target.Address Then
                 bResult = True
             End If
         Next shp
     HasImage = bResult
 End Function
```

Comment: What do I Need to Change?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but does your `BottomRightCell` have to be offset (1,1) from the topleft when image sized to one cell?

In my testing your code seemed to fail because of the `BottomRightCell.Address`, with pic sized to one cell, being a row below and a column to the right.

I tested with the following code where I adjusted `BottomRightCell.Addres`s with:

```
And shp.BottomRightCell.Address = Target.Offset(1, 1).Address
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim mypic As Object

    Set mypic = ActiveSheet.Pictures(1)
    PositionPic mypic
    MsgBox HasImage([A1])
    MsgBox mypic.BottomRightCell.Address

End Sub

Public Function HasImage(ByVal Target As Range) As Boolean
    Dim bResult As Boolean
    Dim shp As Shape
    bResult = False
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shp.TopLeftCell.Address = Target.Address _
           And shp.BottomRightCell.Address = Target.Offset(1, 1).Address Then
            bResult = True
        End If
    Next shp
    HasImage = bResult
End Function

Public Sub PositionPic(ByVal mypic As Object)
    With mypic
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Left
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Top
        .Width = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Width
        .Height = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Height
    End With
End Sub
```